# Can I vote more than once on each The DAO proposal?

Tags: the-dao

An individual has stated in The DAO Forum thread [Has the voting began](https://forum.daohub.org/t/has-the-voting-began/3826/12) that they have been able to vote more than once on a proposal.

Can I vote more than once on each The DAO proposal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is the `vote()` function from The DAO's [source code](http://etherscan.io/address/0xbb9bc244d798123fde783fcc1c72d3bb8c189413#code).

```
function vote(
    uint _proposalID,
    bool _supportsProposal
) onlyTokenholders noEther returns (uint _voteID) {

    Proposal p = proposals[_proposalID];
    if (p.votedYes[msg.sender]
        || p.votedNo[msg.sender]
        || now >= p.votingDeadline) {

        throw;
    }

    if (_supportsProposal) {
        p.yea += balances[msg.sender];
        p.votedYes[msg.sender] = true;
    } else {
        p.nay += balances[msg.sender];
        p.votedNo[msg.sender] = true;
    }

    if (blocked[msg.sender] == 0) {
        blocked[msg.sender] = _proposalID;
    } else if (p.votingDeadline > proposals[blocked[msg.sender]].votingDeadline) {
        // this proposal's voting deadline is further into the future than
        // the proposal that blocks the sender so make it the blocker
        blocked[msg.sender] = _proposalID;
    }

    Voted(_proposalID, _supportsProposal, msg.sender);
}
```

The first conditional statement in the `vote()` function:

```
if (p.votedYes[msg.sender]
    || p.votedNo[msg.sender]
    || now >= p.votingDeadline) {

    throw;
}
```

will **cancel your transaction** (`throw`) if your account has already voted *Yes* (`p.votedYes[msg.sender]`) or voted *No* (`p.votedNo[msg.sender]`) on a proposal.

Your transaction will also be cancelled if you are voting past the proposal voting deadline (`now >= p.votingDeadline`).

A little bit of gas (ether) will be used up when your transaction is cancelled.

---

### Testing My Hypothesis

Here are two transactions sending votes for the same proposal from the same account:

- [Tx 0x4c69fbf18b0274bc73bdaa1f55db86f37b75ca9336c7a756924115731bf3e42e](http://etherscan.io/tx/0x4c69fbf18b0274bc73bdaa1f55db86f37b75ca9336c7a756924115731bf3e42e)
- [Tx 0x6cb6dd1cc4d9555f080077ef1ef16ce5bd44921a8386ec9f945578720044ca13](http://etherscan.io/tx/0x6cb6dd1cc4d9555f080077ef1ef16ce5bd44921a8386ec9f945578720044ca13)

These two transactions are both calls to the `vote()` function as the signature using `web3.sha3('vote(uint256,bool)').substr(0, 10)` produces the result `0xc9d27afe` that matches the start of the Input Data in both transactions.

And here is the second transaction showing the cancellation of the transaction.
[image]

The first transaction fee was 0.001489425 ether, and the second cancelled transaction fee was 0.00315 ether. Note that the second cancelled transaction costed more than the first successful transaction.

---

### MyEtherWallet Vs Ethereum Wallet (Mist)

Results update from an anonymous helpful DAOHub Forum user:

- MyEtherWallet will currently allow you to vote more than once on the same proposal from the same account.
- Ethereum Wallet (Mist) will inform you after your first vote that the account is locked. If you choose to proceed, it show you a message "Data can't be executed, so it will use all provided gas" before executing the transaction.

Comment: "MyEtherWallet will currently allow you to vote more than once on the same proposal from the same account." <- Working on how to fix this. It's a fun solution that might interest you: call vote function with the estimateGas() Function. If all the gas is used, it means a Exception would be thrown, so the user has already voted or the user is not allowed or the end of the debate-period is reached.

Comment: You are right that `estimateGas()` might interest me (am I that predictable?). I've now created a Perl script to list proposals, list the voting status of each account against the proposals and vote on the proposals - from the command line. Using the `estimateGas()` method to check on the voting status. See https://github.com/bokkypoobah/TheDAOVoter/blob/master/theDAOVoter . Thanks @tayvano.